# Fast way to compute barycentric lagrange interpolation

Tags: interpolation

Is there any fast way to compute the barycentric Lagrange interpolation using matlab?

Comment: Consider asking at [scicomp.se]

Comment: What is your setup here?  An affine interpolation from values specified at the vertices of a reference simplex?  Or something else?

Comment: In addition to the information hardmath requested, you should specify what you mean by "fast."  (Or, at least, the size of your dataset.)  Contrary to what some may think, though, software of use to mathematicians **IS** on-topic on this site per the FAQ.

Comment: I am trying to use Lagrange interpolation for chebyshev nodes. I know that Barycentric method is a fast implementation of Lagrange interpolation. Is there any other way which be faster?